# Mplayer can't play *.wmv file

Tags: 11.10, mplayer

I have a problem when I use the mplayer to play *.wmv file on my ubuntu11.10.
There are some error messages here. Could anyone can help me solve this problem. I use some keyword to search in Gooele, but I can't find the answer. Thank you.

```
Playing testmovie.wmv.
ASF file format detected.
[asfheader] Audio stream found, -aid 1
[asfheader] Video stream found, -vid 2
VIDEO:  [WMV3]  1280x720  24bpp  1000.000 fps  4000.0 kbps (488.3 kbyte/s)
Load subtitles in ./
open: No such file or directory
[    MGA] Couldn't open: /dev/mga_vid
open: No such file or directory
[MGA] Couldn't open: /dev/mga_vid
[VO_TDFXFB] Can't open /dev/fb0: Permission denied.
[VO_3DFX] Unable to open /dev/3dfx.
[vdpau] Error when calling vdp_device_create_x11: 1
==========================================================================
Opening video decoder: [dmo] DMO video codecs
DMO dll supports VO Optimizations 0 1
DMO dll might use previous sample when requested
MPlayer interrupted by signal 11 in module: init_video_codec
```

I am using xv as my video driver.

Comment: what video driver are you using? What are the specs of your system?

Comment: I use the xv as my video driver.

Comment: Repo mplayer packages will default to a -vo vdpau unless specified otherwise, either in the cli or thru ~/.mplayer/config. Please try mplayer -vo xv /path/to/file.wmv. If need be run mplayer in verbose (mplayer -v -vo xv /path/to/file.wmv) & paste complete terminal output here http://paste.ubuntu.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Playing testmovie.wmv.
>
> ASF file format detected.

Try using VLC Player. It plays almost all media files without any problem.

ASF is a container for WMA, WMV and MPEG4 file formats, and VLC helps in encoding and decoding this so that the file plays seamlessly on your system.

[VLC and ASF File Format](http://wiki.videolan.org/ASF)

The most relevant part of this page being the line on top, saying :

> VLC can encode and decode this container.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, what if I just want to know why caused this problem. I tried VLC before, but I think mplayer is better than it.

Comment: I'm not too sure if this will work for you, but there's no harm in trying. go to Preferences -> Video, and if possible, change from xv to gl.

Comment: I will try later. BTW, I download VLC and found that when I use VLC to play the *.rmvb file, it's seems a little lag. I mean that the act of video seems not smoothly as using mplayer. Do you have the same problem ?

Answer (score 0):

This has been listed as a bug on Launchpad [#664848](https://bugs.launchpad.net/medibuntu/+bug/664848) against the medibuntu package.

Try `mplayer -vc ffwmv3 /path/to/yourfile` and see if it resolves your problem.